# Retrieve >901 rows from SQL Server 2008 linked server to Active Directory

Tags: sql-server-2008, active-directory, linked-server

In SQL Server 2008 (version 10.0.4000) I have created a linked server to an Active Directory server.

This query:

```
select  TOP 901 *
from  openquery(adsisca, '
select  givenName,
                sn,
                sAMAccountName          
from    ''LDAP://10.1.2.3:389''
where   objectCategory = ''Person''
        and
        objectClass = ''InetOrgPerson''
')
```

works.

However changing the query and trying to retrieve 902 rows does not :

```
select  TOP 902 *
    from  openquery(adsisca, '
    select  givenName,
                    sn,
                    sAMAccountName          
    from    ''LDAP://10.1.2.3:389''
    where   objectCategory = ''Person''
            and
            objectClass = ''InetOrgPerson''
    ')
```

The error is:

> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB
>   provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked
>   server "adsisca".

I've found other instances of people discussing the same problem on forums and they never fixed it, just worked around it writing multiple views and union'ing them together for example.

Is there a more elegant fix, is there a setting I can change somewhere to retrieve more than 901 rows?

Comment: I don't know if there is a link but on a current search request Active-Directory never answer more than 1000 records, and there is perhaps a more restrictive value due to the volume. A directory does not baheve like a database on this point of view.

Answer (score 9):

Use union to circumvent the limitation ..

like this :

```
select  TOP 901 *
from  openquery(adsisca, '
select  givenName,
                sn,
                sAMAccountName          
from    ''LDAP://10.1.2.3:389''
where   objectCategory = ''Person''
        and
        objectClass = ''InetOrgPerson''
        and
        sAMAccountName < ''m''
')
union
select  TOP 901 *
from  openquery(adsisca, '
select  givenName,
                sn,
                sAMAccountName          
from    ''LDAP://10.1.2.3:389''
where   objectCategory = ''Person''
        and
        objectClass = ''InetOrgPerson''
        and
        sAMAccountName >= ''m''
')
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but I too had the same issues, and examined the proposed solution above. (Basically using a bunch of smaller selects with a changing criteria to keep the row count down) I just cut a slightly different version of it, and unioned them all into a Db View. I couldn't be bothered with that MaxPageSize thing - it looks too much effort.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.servers WHERE name = 'ADSI') 
    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'ADSI', 'Active Directory Services 2.5', 'ADSDSOObject', 'adsdatasource'

-- Create a database view from unions of smaller selects. The max 901 records thing in AD forces us to do this.
DECLARE @queryFormat VARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, ''
    SELECT userPrincipalName, samAccountName, telephoneNumber, mail, middleName, givenName, sn, displayName, distinguishedName
    FROM ''''LDAP://OU=Users, OU=ABC, DC=XYZ, DC=local''''
    WHERE objectClass = ''''User'''' AND objectCategory = ''''Person'''' AND samAccountName = ''''#p0'''''')';

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE VIEW [AdView] AS ';
DECLARE @asciiValue INT = ASCII('A');
DECLARE @asciiEnd INT = ASCII('Z');
WHILE @asciiValue <= @asciiEnd BEGIN 
    SET @sql = @sql + replace(@queryFormat, '#p0', CHAR(@asciiValue) + '*');
    IF @asciiValue < @asciiEnd  SET @sql = @sql + ' UNION ALL ';
    SET @asciiValue = @asciiValue + 1;
END
--PRINT @sql;

-- the 'live' view of the active directory data.
IF OBJECT_ID('[AdView]') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW [AdView]
EXEC(@sql);

-- a 'snapshot' of the active directory data, for faster selects. you could execute this on a schedule to keep up to date.
IF OBJECT_ID('[AdTable]', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [AdTable]
SELECT * INTO [AdTable] FROM [AdView]
```

Comment: Work like a charm for me on 2008.

Answer (score 3):

## **The problem**

> > The error is:
> >
> > Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "adsisca".
>
> I've found other instances of people discussing the same problem on forums and they never fixed it, >just worked around it writing multiple views and union'ing them together for example.
>
> Is there a more elegant fix, is there a setting I can change somewhere to retrieve more than 901 >rows?

## **The solution**

I just solved the same problem faced by me, without going for any Active Directory setting changes (and I am successfully able to retrieve around 50k logins from the AD and it is not missing to fetch a single login account from the AD domains):

You need to work around the ADSI query limitation by looping through the characters of the attributes. See a solution here:  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic231658-54-1.aspx#bm1249991

The error was resolved by writing `SELECT TOP 901 ...` IN PLACE OF JUST `SELECT`.

This problem occurred to me after migration of the database from 2005 to 2008, because in SQL Server 2008, there is a limit of 901 rows which was 1000 in SQL Server 2005 (the difference is we need to write select TOP 901, which was not required in the SQL Server 2005, else the program fails with error)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the MaxPageSize setting in Active Directory.  To do that you need to use Ntdsutil.exe which you can type on the run command then follow these steps

1. At the Ntdsutil.exe command prompt, type `LDAP policies`, and then press ENTER.
2. At the LDAP policy command prompt, type `Set MaxPageSize to 2000`. -> Or any number you want
3. To view the changes, type `Show Values`
4. To save the changes, type`Commit Changes`
5. To quit, type `q`

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to change the page size as it has other implications. With .NET I can simply tell it what the page size is and it works - What I'm looking for really is a way to set the page size in my SQL query. (Sorry for late reply, been away)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't like the smell of other options posted here that much, because with a large domain its very possible to have more than 901 accounts starting with the same first letter - particularly if you are looking at computer accounts, which likely follow some systematic naming convention using the same first letter...

I did some playing around and I found that if you order the openquery by uSNCreated and put a TOP 901 clause on the outer query it doesn't blow up.

So, here is my SQL which fetches ALL active directory objects (computers, domain controllers, users and contacts) into a temp table in chunks of 901 records and gives you some useful information on each object.

```
CREATE TABLE #ADData(
    Login           NVARCHAR(256)
    ,CommonName     NVARCHAR(256)
    ,GivenName      NVARCHAR(256)
    ,FamilyName     NVARCHAR(256)   
    ,DisplayName    NVARCHAR(256)
    ,Title          NVARCHAR(256)
    ,Department     NVARCHAR(256)
    ,Location       NVARCHAR(256)
    ,Info           NVARCHAR(256)
    ,LastLogin      BIGINT
    ,flags          INT
    ,Email          NVARCHAR(256)
    ,Phone          NVARCHAR(256)   
    ,Mobile         NVARCHAR(256)
    ,Quickdial      NVARCHAR(256)
    , usnCreated    INT
)

DECLARE @Query      VARCHAR (2000)
DECLARE @Filter     VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @Rowcount   INT

select @Filter =''

WHILE ISNULL(@rowcount,901)  = 901 BEGIN

    SELECT @Query = '
    SELECT top 901
            Login           = SamAccountName
            , CommonName    = cn
            , GivenName
            , FamilyName    = sn    
            , DisplayName
            , Title
            , Department
            , Location      = physicalDeliveryOfficeName
            , Info
            , LastLogin     = CAST(LastLogon AS bigint)
            , flags         = CAST (UserAccountControl as int)
            , Email         = mail
            , Phone         = telephoneNumber
            , Mobile        = mobile
            , QuickDial     = Pager
            , usnCreated
        FROM OPENROWSET(''ADSDSOObject'', '''', ''
                SELECT cn, givenName, sn, userAccountControl, lastLogon, displayName, samaccountname, 
                title,  department, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, info, mail, telephoneNumber, mobile, pager, usncreated
            FROM ''''LDAP://[ldap-query-string]'''' 
            WHERE objectClass=''''Person''''
            AND objectClass = ''''User''''
            ' + @filter + '
            ORDER BY usnCreated'')'             
    INSERT INTO #ADData EXEC (@Query) 
    SELECT @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
    SELECT @Filter = 'and usnCreated > '+ LTRIM(STR((SELECT MAX(usnCreated) FROM #ADData)))

END

SELECT LOGIN            
        , CommonName    
        , GivenName
        , FamilyName
        , DisplayName
        , Title         
        , Department
        , Location      
        , Email         
        , Phone         
        , QuickDial     
        , Mobile        
        , Info          
        , Disabled      = CASE WHEN CAST (flags AS INT) & 2 > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END 
        , Locked        = CASE WHEN CAST (flags AS INT) & 16  > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END 
        , NoPwdExpiry   = CASE WHEN CAST (flags AS INT) & 65536  > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END 
        , LastLogin     = CASE WHEN ISNULL(CAST (LastLogin AS BIGINT),0) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 
                            DATEADD(ms, (CAST (LastLogin AS BIGINT) / CAST(10000 AS BIGINT)) % 86400000,
                            DATEADD(day, CAST (LastLogin AS BIGINT) / CAST(864000000000 AS BIGINT) - 109207, 0)) END 
        , Type = CASE WHEN flags  & 512 = 512 THEN 'user' 
                    WHEN flags IS NULL THEN 'contact' 
                    WHEN flags & 4096 = 4096 THEN 'computer'
                    WHEN flags & 532480 = 532480 THEN 'computer (DC)' END
FROM #ADData
ORDER BY Login

DROP TABLE #ADData
```

Comment: But `uSNCreated` may not be unique. Would it be possible to partition the result with `objectGUID` instead?

Answer (score 2):

I appreciated John Sinclair's answer so much, I've decided on the highest form of flattery - imitation. Here's my rendition of his solution. Instead of declaring the ADSI LDAP connection with every query in the OpenRowSet, I've opted for the OpenQuery method:

```
DECLARE @DomainFQDN VARCHAR(50) = '<your.domain.FQDN>';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ADData') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #ADData;

-- Query AD for all known user accounts
CREATE TABLE #ADData(
    lanId               NVARCHAR(256),
    firstName           NVARCHAR(256),
    lastName            NVARCHAR(256),
    email               NVARCHAR(256),
    costcenter          NVARCHAR(256),  --Our AD implementation uses the optional extensionAttributes, defining 1 as cost center
    mobile              NVARCHAR(256),  --In @Query below, the name of this column is the same as the LDAP returned parameter, so no equate is applied in the query
    country             NVARCHAR(256),
    usnCreated          BIGINT         --uSNCreated is an INT64 object type
);

--Define the AD LDAP connection
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.servers WHERE name = 'ADSI') 
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
    @server = N'ADSI', 
    @srvproduct = N'Active Directory Services',
    @provider = N'ADsDSOObject', 
    @datasrc = @DomainFQDN;

DECLARE @Rowcount int;
DECLARE @LastCreatedFilter VARCHAR(200) = '';
DECLARE @ADrecordsToReturn smallint = 901;  --AD will not return more than 901 records per query (changed from 1000 at some point). You can set it to any value smaller to control the 'pagesize' of returned results

--Loop mechanics:
-- - 1st loop: @Rowcount will be NULL but we need to looping to commence, thus ISNULL function
-- - Intermediate loops: Rowcount will equal the max number of requested records, indicating there may be more to query from AD
--SELECT @LastCreatedFilter = 'AND usnCreated = ''''<yourvalue>'''''; --Used during debugging to iniate the loop at a certain value
--DECLARE @TestStop int = 1;  -- @TestStop is a debug option to halt processing. It needs to be commented in or out at 3 places
WHILE ISNULL(@Rowcount,@ADrecordsToReturn) = @ADrecordsToReturn --AND @TestStop < 4  --Un-comment the three @TestStop lines to run a reduced sample query of AD, dictated by the value provided on this line (# of loops to process before stopping)
 BEGIN

    DECLARE @Query VARCHAR (2000) = 
     '
        SELECT TOP ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@ADrecordsToReturn) + '
            lanId               = SamAccountName,
            firstName           = GivenName,
            lastName            = sn,
            email               = mail,
            bsbcc               = extensionAttribute1,
            mobile,
            country             = c,
            usnCreated
         FROM OpenQuery
          (
            ADSI,
            ''
                SELECT SamAccountName, GivenName, sn, mail, extensionAttribute1, mobile, c, usnCreated
                 FROM ''''LDAP://' + @DomainFQDN + '''''
                 WHERE objectCategory = ''''Person''''
                 AND objectClass = ''''user''''
                 ' + @LastCreatedFilter + '
                 ORDER BY usnCreated
            ''
          )
     ';  
    INSERT INTO #ADData EXEC (@Query);
    SELECT @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;
    SELECT @LastCreatedFilter = 'AND usnCreated > ' + LTRIM(STR((SELECT MAX(usnCreated) FROM #ADData)));
--PRINT @LastCreatedFilter;  --While debugging, used to determine progress
--SET @TestStop = @TestStop + 1;  -- @TestStop is a debug option to halt processing. It needs to be commented in or out at 3 places
 END;

EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver 'ADSI';

--Do something with the results...
SELECT lanId, email, costcenter, mobile, country, usnCreated FROM #ADData order by lanId;
```

Comment: So I found something very odd using the above solution: it worked fine on my prod AD content, but crashed reading my test AD. Then when I tried to troubleshoot, I found the values returned for usnCreated by the TSQL query were sequential and didn't match the usnCreated values returned by Get-ADUser.

Comment: It turns out John's solution was wrong in one regard - uSNCreated from AD is an INT64 value, so requires a SQL 'BIGINT' data type. My code has been corrected, and updated with more comments and debug options

Answer (score 0):

I need to change the MaxTempTableSize setting in Active Directory. To do that you need to use Ntdsutil.exe which you can type on the run command then follow these steps

```
At the Ntdsutil.exe command prompt, type LDAP policies, and then press ENTER.
At the LDAP policy command prompt, type Set MaxTempTableSize to 2000. -> Or any number you want
To view the changes, type Show Values
To save the changes, typeCommit Changes
To quit, type q
```

Answer (score 0):

This version of the solution deals with situations where the number of users beginning with the specified character is still > 901.  It uses a master procedure calling another stored procedure.

```
-- This procedure pulls a subset of LDAP users

CREATE PROC [dbo].[Select_LDAP_Rows]
(
    @MyChar CHAR(1)
)
AS
BEGIN

--DECLARE @MyChar CHAR(1) = 'A';

DECLARE @queryFormat VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, ''
        SELECT displayName, telephoneNumber, mail, mobile, facsimileTelephoneNumber
        FROM ''''LDAP://OU=PHC,dc=MyCompany,dc=org''''
        WHERE objectClass = ''''User'''' AND objectCategory = ''''Person'''' AND displayName = ''''' + @MyChar + '#p0'''''')
    ';

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE VIEW [AdView] AS ';
DECLARE @asciiValue INT = ASCII('A');
DECLARE @asciiEnd INT = ASCII('Z');

WHILE @asciiValue <= @asciiEnd BEGIN 
    SET @sql = @sql + replace(@queryFormat, '#p0', CHAR(@asciiValue) + '*');
    IF @asciiValue < @asciiEnd  SET @sql = @sql + ' UNION ALL ';
    SET @asciiValue = @asciiValue + 1;
END

--PRINT @sql;

-- the 'live' view of the active directory data.
IF OBJECT_ID('v_ADView') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW v_ADView

EXEC(@sql);

-- ADTable holds a 'snapshot' of the active directory data.
IF OBJECT_ID('[Users_AD]', 'U') IS NULL
    SELECT DisplayName, TelephoneNumber AS Phone, Mail, Mobile, FacsimileTelephoneNumber AS Fax 
    INTO [Users_AD] FROM v_ADView;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO [Users_AD] 
    SELECT DisplayName, TelephoneNumber AS Phone, Mail, Mobile, FacsimileTelephoneNumber AS Fax 
    FROM v_ADView;

END


GO


-- By calling Select_LDAP_Rows with a separate character each time,
-- build up a table containing all the LDAP data for each user.

ALTER PROC [dbo].[Select_LDAP_Rows_Master]
AS

BEGIN

-- ADTable holds a 'snapshot' of the active directory data.
IF OBJECT_ID('[AdTable]', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [AdTable];

-- Create a database view from unions of smaller selects. The max 901 records thing in AD forces us to do this.

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @asciiValue INT = ASCII('A');
DECLARE @asciiEnd INT = ASCII('Z');

-- Create a view of the active directory data and insert to table Users_AD
WHILE @asciiValue <= @asciiEnd BEGIN 

    SET @sql = 'EXEC dbo.Select_LDAP_Rows ' + CHAR(@asciiValue) + ' ';
    SET @asciiValue = @asciiValue + 1;

    --PRINT @sql;

    EXEC(@sql);

END

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the union option is the best and simple.

select  TOP 901 *
from  openquery(adsisca, '
select  givenName,
                sn,
                sAMAccountName
from    ''LDAP://10.1.2.3:389''
where   objectCategory = ''Person''
        and
        objectClass = ''InetOrgPerson''
        and
        sAMAccountName < ''m''
')
union
select  TOP 901 *
from  openquery(adsisca, '
select  givenName,
                sn,
                sAMAccountName
from    ''LDAP://10.1.2.3:389''
where   objectCategory = ''Person''
        and
        objectClass = ''InetOrgPerson''
        and
        sAMAccountName >= ''m''
')

Answer (score 0):

All solutions based on `sAMAccountName` attribute are invalid. 
If you need to be sure that you receive all results than you have to build the query differently.
Attribute `sAMAccountName` can contain other than letters/numbers characters in the beggining of the attribute string. 
Other issue is that you have to add another logic to handle situation that result for one specific character at firt position gives more than 901 rows - e.g. due to specific naming convention.

I found another more precise solution.
It is possible to 'partition' AD using `objectguid` attribute.

This filter

```
(&(objectclass=user)(!(objectclass=computer))
(objectguid<=\0f\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff\ff)
(objectguid>=\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00))
```

will results in list of all user accounts with object guid attribute
`0x0000000000000000000000000000000`0 to `0x0fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`

next query in range will be
`0x10000000000000000000000000000000` to `0x1fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`
...

With just 16 requests (union all) you can read entire AD with about 14000 records in total. For larger amount of records you have to customize the margins but it is more simple to do it than to work with character on 2nd/3rd/... position of `sAMAccountName`.

Good on `objectguid` is that it is generated randomly in way that above partitioning scheme gives very close row counts for every of each 16 requests (in my case I have about 8500 user accounts and each request gives me +/- 500 rows result).

Answer (score 0):

You can increase 1000 Records Maximum Page Size of Active Directory using the Ntdsutil.exe (run it as Administrator)

1. At the Ntdsutil.exe command prompt, type “LDAP policies”, and then hit ENTER.
2. Now type “Set MaxPageSize to 5000”. -> Change 5000 to the Max results you want
3. To view the changes, type “Show Values”
4. To commit the changes, type “Commit Changes”
5. type “q” to quit