# LDAP SSIS Throwing generic error on ADO.NET Datasource

Tags: ado.net, ssis, ldap, oledb

When running my SSIS using LDAP, I get this error on my ADO Datasource:

> [LDAP Source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfLvx.png)] Error: The component "LDAP Source" (1) was unable to
>   process the data. 'ADsDSOObject' failed with no error message
>   available, result code: -2147016669(0x80072023).
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
>   PrimeOutput method on component "LDAP Source" (1) returned error code
>   0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline
>   engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is
>   defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline
>   stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.

I have an ADO Connection set up in my Connection Manager as an ADO.NET Connection using a OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services. Example below:

[image]

I'm using an ADO.NET Datasource to Query my AD using an LDAP query that looks like this:

```
SELECT sAMAccountName,cn FROM 'LDAP://DC=domain,DC=net' WHERE sAMAccountType = 805306368
```

When running a preview of my Data, it pulls a preview nicely. But when running the package, it doesn't get past the Datasource without throwing the above error. Note: I've also attempted to change the ADSI Flag to 1 on the ADO.NET Connection.

Has anyone else seen this error before when using a ADO.NET Connection with an OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services Provider?

Comment: I get warnings about data type incompatibilities with the ADO.NET provider and the AD types but I was able to pull back sAMAccountName and cn just fine from my local AD. I'll play around and see if I can find anything,

Comment: You aren't trying to read in something like memberof in your select list, right? Is the above the full column list? Tried deleting and readding the ado net source? Whittle the select list down to 1 column and slowly re-add them, see if you can figure out what's inducing the failure. On the Advanced Editor for the source, look at your columns DataType's, are they all unicode stream (DT_NTEXT)

Comment: After trying all of these options I'm still getting the same error. Could it be something on the AD side that has to be enabled? I can't see it being permission errors as when I click "Preview" on the Datasource, it pulls values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at my answer to [Error : Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594775/error-cannot-fetch-a-row-from-ole-db-provider-adsdsoobject-for-linked-server/9012248#9012248) and see if any of it helps. This always seems to work for me.

Also, you may want to consider changing MaxPageSize in Active Directory using ntdsutil.exe. See [How to view and set LDAP policy in Active Directory by using Ntdsutil.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315071) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ADO.NET Provider as your source for SSIS Packages using OLE DB. It will perform the same operations without all of the errors that you're probably running into. I've resolved every error I had while using ADO.NET because I thought it was the proper thing to use for my SQL Server Data Source. Unfortunately, no matter how many forums I've researched, I simply removed the ADO.NET and replaced it with OLE DB using the exact same connections and settings and have always had a clean "**Success**" Execution.