# Retrieve more than 901 records from Active Directory in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory

I have created a linked server to AD in SQL Server, and tried some logic but I'm not able to retrieve more than 901 records from AD.

This is my query - I have used `top 900` so that the query doesn't throw errors + records

```
SELECT TOP 900 
   UPPER(sAMAccountName)[EmpCode], 
   givenName [FirstName],
   ISNULL(sn, '') [LastName],
   ISNULL(mail, 'NA') [Email],
   telephoneNumber [Telephone], cn [DisplayName],
   Mobile, title [Designation],
   CASE 
       WHEN UserAccountControl = 512 THEN 'Active' 
       WHEN UserAccountControl = 514 THEN 'In-Active' 
       WHEN UserAccountControl = 66048 THEN 'Active, password never expires' 
       WHEN UserAccountControl = 66050 THEN 'In-Active, password never expires'  
       ELSE 'NA' 
   END [Status],
   UserAccountControl,
   UPPER(ISNULL(physicalDeliveryOfficeName, 'NA')) [Office]
--into #temp 
FROM 
    OPENQUERY(ADSI, 
              'SELECT sAMAccountName, givenName, sn, mail, l, St, postalCode, co, telephoneNumber, cn, Mobile, title, UserAccountControl, physicalDeliveryOfficeName
               FROM ''LDAP://domain.local/OU=Company,DC=domain,DC=local'' where objectClass = ''User'' ')

-- I added this line to get records apart from records I already have
WHERE 
    sAMAccountName NOT IN (SELECT code FROM tbl_usermaster)
```

Any loop or any other logic will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Comment: @Agar123 what about it?


This below is the error, as AD has limitation of  901 errors :

Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI".

Comment: You can read here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16163747/10819830