# How to import Active Directory data into a SQL Server table using query?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
CREATE TABLE T_AD_Data
(
    lab_sAMAccountName varchar(100),
    lab_displayName varchar(100),
    lab_department varchar(100),
    lab_physicalDeliveryOfficeName varchar(100), 
);

INSERT INTO T_AD_Data
   SELECT * 
   FROM OpenQuery (ADSI,  
                   'SELECT sAMAccountName, displayName, department, physicalDeliveryOfficeName 
                    FROM ''LDAP://lab.com/DC=lab,DC=com'' 
                    WHERE objectClass =  ''User'' ') AS tblADSI
```

Error:

> Msg 7330, level 16, state 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DBprovider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI"

Comment: Maybe, you are over the limit of rows fetched by an OPENQUERY command

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but the problem you've hit is caused by the ADSI query returning more than 901 records.  Prior to SQL 2008 this didn't cause a problem, the number of records was just limited.  But on SQL 2008 or later, when you hit this limit instead of the results being truncated, a runtime error occours.

Work around this problem with some sort of paging solution that uses multiple queries, like in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43057890/197090